# getting below error while starting the tomcat 8.5 server

Tags: java, tomcat8

Getting below error while starting the server.

using **tomcat 8.5**.

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
>       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:215)
>       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:196)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4730)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5194)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport$6.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.findJarServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getNonValidatingBuilder(ConfigManager.java:513)
>       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getDocument(ConfigManager.java:468)
>       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:416)
>       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:373)
>       ... 4 more

Comment: Do you use JSF? can you create the configuration inside the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Your settings in sun faces web.xml (faces-config.xml) file may be incorrect? Otherwise, your sun faces config file in  may have incorrect permissions for the server to read the file? The top error is sun faces, and about half way down you are getting security exceptions.  You may have to uninstall and reinstall with admin privledges if you are windows or similar procedure on unix.